# Android OCR Using Tesseract

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to built an OCR Application in android using Tesseract Library.

Here is the code attached:

```
public class TessOCR {
    private TessBaseAPI mTess;

public TessOCR() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
    String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tesseract/";
    String language = "sseg";
    File dir = new File(datapath + "tessdata/");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    mTess.init(datapath, language);


}

public String getOCRResult(Bitmap bitmap) {

    mTess.setImage(bitmap);
    String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();

    return result;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (mTess != null)
        mTess.end();
}
```

When I am calling `new TessOCR()` in my MainAcitivity It gives me the error

> 09-02 16:10:56.677  14225-14225/com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar, PID: 14225
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!**
>               at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:344)
>               at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:317)
>               at com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar.TessOCR.(TessOCR.java:22)
>               at com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar.Tab1.doOCR(Tab1.java:326)
>               at com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar.Tab1.access$000(Tab1.java:42)
>               at com.example.pulkitmital.swipetabtoolbar.Tab1$3.onClick(Tab1.java:168)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

But the folder is already there.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Did you train your own language file called `sseg.traineddata`? The traineddata file should go in a subfolder named `tessdata`, which should go in your `tesseract` folder.

Comment: @rmtheis Yeah I have done it. Main Issue is that I forgot to add permission in manifest file

Comment: Glad you got it working. To help others, you should add your solution as an answer here, and check the check mark next to it to choose your own answer as the working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Error is due to I forget to add permission to read from external storage in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Just Add this line to your AndroidManifest and it will get resolved.

---

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line  :

```
mTess.init(datapath, language);
```

with :

```
mTess.init(datapath + "tessdata/", language);
```

Comment: I have already do the change that you told but its giving me error " Data path doest not exist!"

Comment: You could try create this folder after request mTess.init. Can you try it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually the problem is that i forgot to add permission for reading storage in manifest file.